# Name for map from AB to BA

Tags: matrices

Is there a canonical name for a mapping from a (square) matrix $M=AB$ to another (square) matrix $N=BA$?

Edited for more context: This map depends on the choice of decomposition for M (different choices of decomposition producing different A and B matrices), but once the decomposition is defined, then the rearrangement of AB to BA follows directly.

I'm particularly interested in the case where I have two sets of bases $U$ and $V$ on a vector space, and metrics $M_1$ and $M_{2}$, such that $U$ is orthonormal with respect to $M_{1}$ and $V$ is orthonormal with respect to $M_{2}$.

If I have a Jacobian J that linearly maps vector coefficients in $U$ to vector coefficients in $V$, then the metric tensor for $M_{2}$ on $U$ is $J^{T}J$ and the metric tensor for $M_{1}$ on $V$ is $J^{-T}J^{-1}$.

I'm looking for a term to describe the relationship between $M_{2}$ on $U$ and $M_{1}$ on $V$. They are not inverses of each other ($M_{2U}^{-1} = J^{-1}J^{-T}$), but the operation I describe would map $M_{2U}^{-1}$ to $M_{1V}$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this map makes sense. It depends on the  expression for $M$. For instance take a pair of matrices $A$ and $B$ that do not commute. Then $M=AB$ would be sent to $BA=N\ne M$. However, if we write $M=I_n\cdot M$, then $M$ should also be sent to $M\cdot I_n=M$. So, we get two distinct answers depending on the decomposition of $M$ into a pair of matrices.

Comment: Yes, the mapping depends on the decomposition. I’m looking for a term that describes the action of decomposing M into A and B, then using A and B to construct N. Edited question for context.